# How to create an HTML file using fs.writefile

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs

I need to create an HTML file using `fs.writefile`. I now have a txt file (*menuOutput.txt*) with all the information that I need to display on the HTML. It looks like this :

**Lunch Items**

17.26  bento box b - sashimi, box combo

15.46  bento box a - chicken teriyaki, box combo

**Dinner Items**

6.30  vegetable sushi, 6 rolls

8.10  tuna roll, 3 rolls

7.11  roe, 2 rolls

```
Function createHTML (textFile) {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.readFile(textFile, 'utf8', (err,data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            resolve (data)
        })
    })
}

createHTML('menuOutput.txt') 
        .then(data=>{
            fs.writeFile ('index.html', data, (err) => {
                console.log (data)
                if (err) {
                    if (err) throw err
                    console.log ('created')

                }
            })
        })
```

However, my HTML file is just a single line of text, how can I implement HTML tag in the function? Or is there anything wrong with my way of thinking?

Comment: Saving plain text in a .html file doesn't magically create tags. You've to create the tags to the content before saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code modification.

```
createHTML('menuOutput.txt').then(data=>
    {
        var stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.html', {flags: 'a'});
        stream.write(data, function() {
        var html = buildHtml();
        stream.end(html);
        });
    });
```